# How to update MongoDB document preserving array elements

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection with documents like the one created from starting_dict below:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
test = MongoClient(mongo_connection_string).database_name.test

starting_dict = {
    'Colors': [ 'green', 'blue' ],
    'Dimensions': {
        'Lenght': 10,
        'Height': 20
    }
}

test.insert_one( { 'Name': 'Test1', 'Description': starting_dict } )
```

Which gives:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6436a68bc3ada18c371339e9'),
 'Name': 'Test1',
 'Description': {'Colors': ['green', 'blue'],
  'Dimensions': {'Lenght': 10, 'Height': 20}}}
```

Now, I would like to update the document with another dict:

```
updated_dict = {
    'Colors': [ 'yellow' ],
    'Dimensions': {
        'Depth': 5
    }
}
```

And my need is that:

- The element "yellow" should be added to the array "Colors"
- The element "Depth" should be added to "Dimensions"

Leaving the other fields unmodified.

However, with this command:

```
test.update_one( { 'Name': 'Test1'}, [ { '$addFields': { 'Description': updated_dict } } ] , upsert=False)
```

I obtain:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6436a68bc3ada18c371339e9'),
 'Name': 'Test1',
 'Description': {'Colors': ['yellow'],
  'Dimensions': {'Lenght': 10, 'Height': 20, 'Depth': 5}}}
```

So, "Dimensions" is correct, but the "Colors" array lost the previous elements from `starting_dict`.

Is there the possibility to preserve array elements while updating a document?